# Graphics In Java

Tags: java

i have shifted my programming from C# to Java for only one project as my teacher told me to do so. I just wanted to ask what is an equivalent of:

```
this.Refresh();
```

in Java?

Comment: And `this` is an object of which class?

Comment: @ZhivkoDraganov yes i am using JFrame.

Comment: Does the `Refresh()` function/method have net browsable documentation?

Comment: You can use validate() or repaint(). They are like refresh(). But I think repaint() is better.

Answer (score 1):

You assume that a Java application is automagically equivalent to Windows Forms which gives you a form you can Refresh to "repaint".
In Java things are more complicated and you should probably read this first:
[How to Create a Simple Java GUI](http://markalexanderbain.suite101.com/how-to-create-a-simple-java-gui-a92244)

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
yourFrame.invalidate();
yourframe.validate();
```

See more information about `invalidate()` and `validate()` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#invalidate%28%29).

Per the documentation: *The **validate** method is used to cause a container to lay out its subcomponents again. It should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified (added to or removed from the container, or layout-related information changed) after the container has been displayed.*

Answer (score 0):

```
    yourFrame.invalidate();
    //make changes here...
    yourFrame.validate();
    yourFrame.repaint();
```

See JFrame documentation for more things you think you will need.